# Add color on height 3D map with Rayshader in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, rayshader

I want to make 3D map with rayshader. I have seen this web https://www.tylermw.com/3d-ggplots-with-rayshader/ and try the code with my data. In this web, height map has black color but not on my output. Are there any way to get result like that? Thanks..

I use this code.

```
map <- sf::st_read('map/map.shp', quiet = TRUE)
gg = ggplot(map) +
   geom_sf(aes(fill =AREA),linewidth=0.7,colour='black',inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    scale_fill_viridis('Area',na.value = 'white')+
   theme(axis.line = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank())
plot_gg(gg, multicore = TRUE, width = 6 ,height=2.7, fov = 70,offset_edges = TRUE)
```

This is snapshot my result.
[image: my output]

This is my expect.
[image: my expect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you are using new version of `ggplot2` 3.4.0. I think your issue is not about adding color but more likely to do with newer version of `ggplot2`, specifically new `linewidth()`. Your color is still correct as black but thinner. This has been documented https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html.

I have also experienced some strange behaviors with `ggplot2` 3.4.0 and `rayshader`. As you can see in the following graph, my 3D graph with `ggplot2` 3.4.0 became unrecognizable.

## rayshader with ggplot 3.4.0

[image]

The only solution I have so far is to switch back to `ggplot2` 3.3.6.

```
library(remotes)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.3.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

You may want to try it, as least as a temporary solution.

## rayshader with ggplot 3.3.6

[image]

Comment: aaaaa that's what I mean, I wonder why the results are different.. Thanks sir, i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely positively certain you are using the current versions of packages? If yes then it could be some tricky environmental issue (I run my R on Linux).

When I run your code I get this - I changed the edges color from black to red to exaggerate the effect; otherwise it is your code, and it seems to behave itself.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rayshader)

map <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # to make reproducible

gg <- ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA),
          linewidth=0.7,
          colour='red', # changed from black to red to exaggerate...
          inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis('Area',na.value = 'white')+
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank())

plot_gg(gg,
        multicore = TRUE, 
        width = 6,
        height=2.7, 
        fov = 70,
        offset_edges = TRUE)

render_snapshot(filename = "nc.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i use the current versions of packages.
map <- st_read(system.file("map/map.shp", package="sf"))
this code is error.
Error: `dsn` must point to a source, not an empty string.

Comment: since I did not have your `map.shp` file I used the one that ships with the `{sf}` package - you need to copy/paste the full line `map <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))`, the shape/nc.shp part is important

Comment: i want to apply that code to my map. should i save my folder in system.file?

Comment: just ignore "my" assignment to the map object and use yours then; it does not matter as long as the object is a sf data frame named `map` and has a field named `AREA`

Comment: hmm how to make sure i use the current version of package? because when i try with same code i have different results.